# Infoblox: I can query the Infoblox REST API from my work laptop using Postman but not from a server at work using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, infoblox

Using the same uri, credentials and wapi endpoint I can make a successful call using Postman on my work Laptop and get json results.  On a Windows Server in my organization I'm using PowerShell to `Invoke-RESTMethod` to reach out to IB.

I don't really know if the error I'm getting is valid.  The error I get from InfoBlox is:

```
403 Forbidden Forbidden You don't have permission to access /wapi/v1.0/ on this server.
```

However, there are some considerations:

1. I'm using the exact same creds and links on my Laptop and it's working there.  So the user I'm using on the Laptop side is making the call and getting results so I'm sure it has permissions.
2. If I put in an invalid userid/pw in my command I get the exact same error ... so it's as if it's not even trying to authenticate first before throwing that error.
3. My laptop lives in an ip range of 170.144.97.xxx .... my server lives in 10.250.152.xxx  the IB server is in the 170.144.32.xxx space.
4. From my Windows Server I can ping the IB server...and a Test-NetConnection  -Port 443 evaluates to true from my Windows Server.

In summary ... my Windows Server seems to see the IB Server ... but the IB server seems to be shutting down any request to use the API before it even tries to authenticate.

**NOTE I seem to recall from our IB guru that we lost a year ago ... was that there is some place to explicitly allow an IP address (or range) to use the API.

Comment: Proxy server at work is blocking/authenticating.

Comment: Thank you ... but it seems like the error message is coming from the Infoblox server ... why would it be returning anything if it's not authenticating?

Comment: Disregard my comment above...after further testing it looks like the 403 error is coming from the server and not necessarily Infoblox.  I tried doing the call to <server>/joeBlow and got the same error that I don't have permission to access /joeBlow on the server.  I will pursue the proxy and/or firewall routes.